# Running eval in Jenkins execute shell

Tags: jenkins, docker

I want to execute  below line of code in Jenkins execute shell

```
eval "$(docker-machine env default)"
```

but it is executing some thing like this

```
docker-machine env default
```

what can I do to make the whole command execute as it is in Jenkins execute shell

Comment: Why do you think it is not working? Please post the Console output. Jenkins  will first execute the inner command, then perform the eval, so the output is expected to contain a line with the inner command, followed eval with the results of the inner command.

Comment: ++ docker-machine env default
+ eval 'export DOCKER_TLS_VERIFY="1"
export DOCKER_HOST="tcp://191.158.89.100:2376"
export DOCKER_CERT_PATH="/Users/pssdk/.docker/machine/machines/default"
export DOCKER_MACHINE_NAME="default"
# Run this command to configure your shell: 
# eval "$(docker-machine env default)"'   this is the exact output of Jenkins